# Routing requests to dev urls from Node server

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have angular spring application which needs Weblogic to be started to test a simple UI changes so i want to host UI on Node server and route all the server requests to the development server URLs. Please suggest how to go about it

Comment: Please submit code or something for us to work with...ideas aren't concrete enuff

Comment: environment variables.   Boom.

Comment: cannot post code here

Comment: Any reference to sample code is highly appreciated